# perl split strange behavior

Tags: regex, perl, split

I apologize in advance, this is probably a very stupid question with an obvious solution which is escaping the eye of a rather beginner in perl, or it may also have been in Stackoverflow as a solved question, but my lack of knowledge about what exactly to look for is preventing me from actually finding the answer.

I have a string like:

```
$s = FOO: < single blankspace> BAR <some whitespace character> some more text with     whitespace that can span over multiple lines, i.e. has \n in them ; 

#please excuse the lack of quotes, and large text describing the character in angular brackets, but in this example, but I have the string correctly defined, and in plase of <blankspace> I have the actual ASCII 32 character etc.
```

Now I want to split the $s, in this way:

```
($instType, $inst, $trailing) = split(/\s*/, $s, 3);
#please note that i do not use the my keyword as it is not in a subroutine
#but i tested with my, it does not change the behavior
```

I would expect, that $instType takes the value FOO: , without any surrounding space, in the actual test string there is a colon, and I believe, to the best of my knowledge, that it will remain in the $instType. Then it is rather obvious to expect that $inst takes similary the value BAR , without any surrounding spaces, and then finally one may also lean on $trail to take the rest of the string.

However, I am getting:
    $instType takes F , that is just the single char,
    $inst takes O, the single charater in the 2nd position in the string
    $trail takes O:  BAR  and the rest.

How do I address the issue?

PS perl is 5.18.0

Comment: You made the `\s*` optional, so it matches nothing whenever it can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the problem is the quantifier `*` that allows zero space (zero or more), you must use `+` instead, that means 1 or more.

Note that there is exactly zero space between F and O.

Comment: uh thank you so much . it asks me to wait 4 minutes till accepting

Comment: @Sean: fröhliche Weihnachten!

Comment: aw, danke sehr, euch auch!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
#please note that i do not use the my keyword as it is not in a subroutine
#but i tested with my, it does not change the behavior
```

You can, and should, use `my` outside of subroutines, too. Using that in conjunction with `use strict` prevents silly errors like this:

```
$some_field = 'bar';
if ( $some_feild ) { ... }
```

If those statements were separated, it could be awfully hard to track down that bug.